# itextpdf, JPEG to PDF (JPEG is showing broken in pdf)

Tags: android, pdf, bitmap

I am trying to generate PDF from existed JPEG image but could not succeed, pdf is generating with broken JPEG image, only first 1/4 of JPEG comes to PDF

Below is my code

```
 public void createPDFFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
        File appDir =  new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        appDir.mkdir();

        String imageFile = appDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator+ "history.jpeg"; // add permission in your manifest...
        String pdfFile = appDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator+ "history.pdf"; // add permission in your manifest...

        File mPdfFile = new File(pdfFile);
        if(mPdfFile.exists()){
            mPdfFile.delete();
        }

        try
        {
            OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(imageFile));
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
            os.close();

            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(pdfFile));
            document.open();
            Image image = Image.getInstance(imageFile);
            document.add(image);
            document.close();
            writer.close();
            shareViaEmail(mPdfFile);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am creating first JPEG and then I use that JPEG filepath and want to convert it into PDF, but unfortunately not able to generate PDF properly

Answer (score 0):

I have done successfully by following code

```
Image image = Image.getInstance(imageFile);
document.setPageSize(image);
document.newPage();
image.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
document.add(image);
```